# Cause of print errors with PC + CF?

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, fdm, polycarbonate

I simply don't have a lot of experience with 3D FDM printing and additionally Priline PC+CF filament.

It does print relatively easily. But a coworker wanted a Batman symbol for his daughter. Now I'm getting problems.

Seems on longer runs when filling in the top or bottom the right side doesn't have enough filament while the left side does.

Then there are these occasional areas where the material... guessing is retracted and causing a lift?

Was going to try disabling it... there are lots of things to try but was hoping for some guidance. Thanks

[image: Photo of first few layers with printing errors highlighted in red]

[image: Photo of first few layers with good printing highlighted in green and print errors in red]

I don't recall having either issue with PLA, especially the bottom. And that didn't manifest until this model.

Printer: Ender 3 S1 Pro
Slicer: MatterControl
Nozzle: 265 °C
Bed: 105 °

Comment: I already changed my Slicer settings. Aside from going into the G code can only give ballpark. Print was ~265C nozzle 105C bed.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you have to remember is that PC/CF filaments are hygroscopic, they absorb lots of moisture from the air very quickly.

So I would begin by drying your filament, and then printing with it inside of a dry air-sealed box such as a food dehydrator or a box of silica packets.

When not using the filament, it is crucial that it is not left out.